# 301 Redirect For Folder Not Working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have some issues with the 301 redirect. Not all the rules are working. I noticed that particularly, rules to redirect a folder is the one not working.

These are among the rules generated by cPanel:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.org$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.org\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.org$
RewriteRule ^subfolder\/$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.org\/" [R=301,L]
```

The first one basically says to redirect `domain.org/index.html` to `domain.org/` and it works fine. But the second one which was meant to redirect `domain.org/subfolder/` to `domain.org` does not.

Can a 301 redirect can redirect access to a folder?

Answer (score 1):

Once you remove the quotes and escape characters from the target in the RewriteRule it should work fine.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.org$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.domain.org/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.org$
RewriteRule ^subfolder/$ http://www.domain.org/ [R=301,L]
```

Subfolder is literal for the word "subfolder" if you're trying to redirect ALL non-existent subfolders, you might try something like this below. `\w` is normally the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and we're also allowing hyphens.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.org$
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ http://www.domain.org/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: actually i meant to redirect a specific subfolder, and not all subfolders.

Comment: @ImpStudent did you try the first part of my answer?